# Jasmine check if an array is empty - fabric js undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, testing, jasmine, fabricjs

I'm starting to use Jasmine to run tests on my code.  Most of the tests so far have been fairly primitive but I'm now facing a problem when checking to see if an array has been populated.

the test is:

```
describe("create grid of layers", function() {
    var result = new Array(4);
    it("returns an array of objects as a grid", function() {
        result = randomQuadrants();
        expect( result).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

I've also tried:

```
describe("create grid of layers", function() {
    var result = new Array(4);
    it("returns an array of objects as a grid", function() {
        expect(result = randomQuadrants()).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

as well but am receiving an error of `ReferenceError: fabric is not defined` at this line `var obj = new fabric.GeologicalObject({` in the following code.

```
function randomQuadrants() {
    var posX, posY;
    posY = 175;

    for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
        //declaring random num here makes each layer the same but random.
        grid[i] = new Array(6);
        posX = 100;

        for(j=0; j<10; j++) {
            //random num here makes each square a random layer
            var randomNum = random_num(layerDetails.length);
            var obj = new fabric.GeologicalObject({
                strength: layerDetails[randomNum].strength,
                minSpeed: layerDetails[randomNum].minSpeed ,
                maxSpeed: layerDetails[randomNum].maxSpeed,
                width: 200,
                height: 75,
                left:  posX,
                top: posY,
                fill: 'red'
            });

            posX = parseInt(posX) + 200;
            loadPattern(obj, layerDetails[randomNum].pattern);
            grid[i][j] = obj;
        }
        posY+=75;
    }
    return grid;
}
```

Thanks for any help!